# async=false workaround for foundation abide

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

I wish to get rid of async=false but I cant seem to find a proper workround

```
$(document).foundation({
  abide : {
    validators: {
      checkUser: function(el, required, parent) {
        var result = $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          url: "../functions/checkUsername.php",
          data:{
            'username': el.value
          }, 
          async: false 
        }).responseText;
        return eval(result);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

FYI: checkUsername.php returns true or false

I have tried several different methods but cant seem to find the best way to modify this function.

Comment: Well I'll just come out n say it.  Did you set it to `true`?  You also may have a `$.ajaxSetup()` turning it on if you're just deleting it.  You need to explain this a little better it's very unclear what your issue is.

Comment: If you turn it off validation returns true every time.  I am tring to avoid using async false because it is depreciated and only a matter of time before you cant use it anymore.

Comment: You need to take over the `submit` event on the form, fire your AJAX and have a callback inside the AJAX that waits for the result.  Then inside that callback, you would call the validators directly (but in your case you would probably just over-ride them and apply invalid or valid manually).  Basically, if this is the only thing you are you using this for, **you don't need abide at all** (except maybe the styling provided).  Abide is for client-side validation so if you're only checking for duplicate usernames you have no need for it.

Comment: I would rather leave it as is then create a ton of extra code to create an external function that applies all the abide classes and attributes that are spidered throughout the css.

Comment: hi James, did you ever solve the problem, neatly?

Comment: Yes after a ton of work I was able to.  I will post the code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with in the end that finally worked out for me.  The first section is a function to mark the field as invalid if the check fails. The second allows you to check against your database through php or whatever you are using.

The first function also allows you to send a string so you can change the message set in the error box in case you have a set format rather than displaying a large message that covers every case.

My php script returns a 1 or a 0.  1 being that the username is available 0 if it is not.

```
$(function(){   
    // Mark Invalid for Username Checks
    $.fn.markInvalid = function(text) {
        $(this).filter(":input").each(function(i, el) {
            console.log($(this).val());
            var input = $(el);
            var container = input.closest(".row");    
            var label = container.find("label");    
            var error = container.find(".form-error");
            label.addClass("is-invalid-label");
            input.attr("data-invalid", "").addClass('is-invalid-input');
            if(text){ error.text(text).addClass('is-visible'); }
        });
    };

    $("#usrnme").on("valid.zf.abide", function(e){
        $.post( "checkUsername.php", {'username': $('#usrnme').val()}, function( data ) {
            if(data!=1){ $(e.target).markInvalid('The username you entered is already taken.'); }
            else{ $('#changeUSR').html('The username must only contain lowercase letters or numbers.'); }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div>
    <label class="label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" >
    <span id="changeUSR" class="form-error">The username must only contain lowercase letters or numbers.</span>
</div>
```